# "copy con" or "type con > " equivalent in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, inline-editing

On Command Prompt, and its syntactical ancestor, DOS, you can create a text file inline by doing this:

```
copy con file.txt
Hello World
^Z
```

Or:

```
type con > file.txt
Hello World
^Z
```

Is there an equivalent command in Powershell? Neither of the two commands I listed above work.

Comment: `cmd /c copy con file.txt`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Yeah, that'd work, but it feels like a cheat. :)

Comment: Even cheatier: `notepad file.txt` Handy, too, since it shows you the file encoding.

Comment: I am very interested in your reasons not to use notepad.exe :)

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo Sometimes it's just a lot easier on my mind to stay focused on one window.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pipe content to the `out-file` cmdlet to emulate this.

```
"Hello World" | out-file hello.txt
```

To get multiple lines, open the quotes but don't close them right away

```
"hello
>> is it me you're looking for" | out-file hello2.txt
```

The `>>` will appear on the second line after hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

Another way is using "here-strings" for this instead of opening quotes.

```
@'
hello
is it me you're looking for?
I can even use ' @ $blabla etc in here
and no substitutes will be placed
You want var substitutes, use @"..."@ instead of @'...'@
'@ | out-file hello.txt
```

Comment: Better. Does the output (in hello2.txt) include the newlines?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yes it does

Comment: Works in the console version, doesn't work in the ISE. Take the point. :)

Comment: As an alternative, use `@'<CR> (multiline string) <CR>'@` to feed string data that contains any symbols, including quotes, apostrophes, backslashes and dollar signs. "<CR>" is a newline.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with underscores.  They're all eliminated from the result.

Comment: @recursive Try PowerShell 7+.